# Kendo UI custom validation rules not validation properly in MVVM

Tags: validation, mvvm, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-validator

Here I have a Kendo view model.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    addData : function (e) {
      if (val.validate()) {
        // this will send data to server if only view is valid. 
      }
    }  
  });

  kendo.bind($("#my-form"), viewModel);

  var val = $("#my-form").kendoValidator({ 
    messages : {
      my custom messages
    },
    rules: {
      my custom rules
    }
  }).data("kendoValidator");
});
```

What happen here, when I try to submit the form it did not validate the form. simply it gets true for `val.validate()`. Then I remove `data("kendoValidator")`  because this is now not a HTML5 validations. So after remove that it is like this...

```
var val = $("#my-form").kendoValidator({
  messages : {
    my custom messages
  },
  rules: {
    my custom rules
  }
});
```

Then I try to submit the form, it refresh the page. Where I have been wrong in this ??

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean. Why did you omit your custom messages and custom rules if that's a potential source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup should work fine. Perhaps it is really matter of validation rules.
By all means you should not remove the

> data("kendoValidator")

part, because this is how you get reference to the Validator object.

Have a look at this example I have prepared for your reference. Let me know if you have further questions.

http://dojo.telerik.com/ovUCA